# Make a post request to a api that uses sanctum via Client (Laravel-6.2)

Tags: laravel, httpclient, laravel-sanctum, laravel-6.2

I have 5 applications that use the same sanctum API for authentication. What I really want to do is to make a `POST` request sanctum API from another application. I do `GET` requests like the below and it's working. But when I make a `POST` request it returns  **csrf token mismatch** error.

So could someone please tell me  **is it possible to make a post request into a sanctum API via Client?**

```
            $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8000/api/user', [
                'headers' => [
                    'accept' => 'application/json',
                    'cookie' => $request->header('cookie'),
                    'referer' => $request->header('referer'),
                ]
            ]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i use `Bearer` instead of `cookie` ,
in sanctum laravel reads access tokens from `Authorization` in header.

this is how i make request from laravel client to sanctum (an example of my code):

```
 $response = Http::withHeaders([
        "Accept"=> "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer " . Cookie::get("Laravel")
    ])
    ->post("http://localhost:8088/api/v1/url/find", ["find" => $request->find]);
```

i send my headers with method `withHeaders` as an associative array
and send my post body with `post` method second argument.

read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Comment: thanks. but im trying with laravel 6.2

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some headers on your requests. You need to first make a request to "/sanctum/csrf-cookie", what gives you a CSRF token. Then you pass that token as the value for the header "X-CSRF-TOKEN". Sanctum documentation explains it very well. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating
Wish you luck!